# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED - what changed?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm not sure what's going on here, I pulled my recently updated repo and every time I open the app to debug it on an emulator I get `E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` as the app loads up the main screen. However this hadn't happened before today so I don't know what could've changed? I deleted the app from the Firebase console and re-added it (through Firebase Assistant), but that didn't fix it either? I've included my build.grade file but I'm not sure what else I need to be looking at, any assistance would be appreciated.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.projectrc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}








apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you authenticated the user?

Comment: yes! I've been using a test account that was created months ago - what doesn't make sense is why this is happening before a user even logs in - I've noticed that sometimes the emulator's internet connection is spotty (which makes even less sense as I'm connected through LAN on my desktop) so I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in my case was that the emulator was not connected to internet, seems that is not implicitly connected like the ios simulator.

Answer (score 5):

Using an emulator ***WITHOUT*** Google Play will cause this error.

Comment: I have the same issue with a real device and before getting the token I check if google play services are updated and they are. I am sure to have network connection too.

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have internet connection in your emulator. I had the same issue and running emulator like this helped me:

`emulator -avd <Avd name> -dns-server 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that a new version of the Google Play library has been released and your test device/emulator need update his currently installed version.

Check the Google Play Store app on your device/emulator, make the update, and you should be good to go !

Answer (score 1):

Cold Boot Device Solved for Android Emulator

Comment: This is not a answer. This should be a comment else please do update your answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same same problem. I was using a Nexus with API 28 and it was buggy and I couldn't update the Google Play.

I had to create another simulator with the API 24 and update the Google Play from the simulator. Now, the email auth and firestore works, but the Facebook and Google login doesn't work despite it works on ios.

Comment: Open the simulator, go to `settings` and then `Google Play` and click on Update. Is not all the devices that you can update. If you having problems updating try a different API like I did going to the 24 instead of 28

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.And the first time I used a Nexus with API 28.

Android Studio prompted me to say that `"2019-06-06 09:16:04.540 4415-4502/com.google.android.youtube E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"`.

Finally,I uninstalled the simulator and install a new Nexus with API 26.The problem was finally solved.

Comment: I have the same issue with a real device and before getting the token I check if google play services are updated and they are. I am sure to have network connection too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve mine by wiping the emulator data in the android studio. You can try this.

Also, my emulator was a Pixel 4 with API 31

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

go to

`Project` -> `Dockerfile` -> download your emulator Api (Api - 28) version on the basis of sdkmanager `platforms;android-28`.

[Check for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfSRO.png)